# Would my question be on-topic for Money.SE?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

I want to ask a question asking why the 'new' chip & pin system in the U.S is considered such a big deal, compared to the rest of the world (who have had this system for a while).

Would my question be on-topic for Money.SE?

I have a feeling that such a question, if asked, would be closed as Primarily Opinion Based (POB):

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the subject matter is on-topic.

However, you could ask instead about the various advantages of the new system, vs. the disadvantages of the old, which should solicit answers containing actual facts and references, rather than "why is it a big deal?", which might lead to opinion-based answers more than fact-based ones. (Who, in fact, has said or considers it a "big deal" in the first place?)

Quite often there is a better way to phrase a question that accomplishes the original goal yet (mostly) avoids the issues you're concerned about.

Comment: I [submitted my question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54772/why-is-the-introduction-of-chip-pin-so-controversial-in-the-united-states) just before I read this.

Comment: You can easily edit, to achieve the subtle difference Chris suggested